# PHP - connecting to mysql database from different server

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database from a different server to the one the database is hosted on but I'm getting an error.

I'm guessing it might be something to do with remote permissions. Is this something I can change or do I need to get my hosting company to do this?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("mysql4-remote.hosting.net","myadmin","password123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql4-remote.hosting.net' (10060)PHP Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql4-remote.hosting.net' (10060) in D:\websites\abc123\www\test.php on line 2`

Comment: is the port 3306 allowed on the other server?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I've contacted technical support because I think they need to allow remote users by request.

Comment: indeed, it can be tunneled as well, see answer below

Answer (score 6):

I would say, that your login credentials or Network settings are wrong:
See this post for further help:
http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_MySQL_error_number_10060_mean

If you don't have access from outside use tunneling, here is an example:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('SERVER IP', 22);  
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password'); 
$tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, 'DESTINATION IP', 3307); 
$db = new mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD',  
                         'dbname', 3307, $tunnel) 
    or die ('Fail: '.mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the permission to remote user by inserting the particular remote machine IP or wildcards in **USER** table in mysql.

This link will help you. [**Click Here**](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3311731/An-introduction-to-MySQL-permissions.htm)