# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'database'

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - connecting to mysql database from different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991130/php-connecting-to-mysql-database-from-different-server)

```
global $host, $username, $password, $database; 
$host = "meshtelecom.com"; 
$username = "mesh_project"; 
$password = "password"; 
$database = "mesh_database"; 
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password); 
if(!$link)echo "Connection failed."; 
$db = mysql_select_db($database)or die(mysql_error());
```

I made a database with phpmyadmin in meshtelecom.com. I can't access this database from another server.. it's giving me:

```
Connection failed.Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mesh_database'
```

Comment: Check `<?php phpinfo();` and search for `mysql.default_port` Default this is 3306 but if this is difference you need to tell the connection.

Comment: A simple portscan on meshtelecom.com on port 3306 says there is no ports open! If you're certain your access config is correct you might want to set your database access on the db host. (then - don't use deprecated mysql_* functions)

Comment: grant user to connect from `localhost`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new account for the user for accessing the host from other servers.
You currently have user 'mesh_project'@'localhost' but you also need to have 'mesh_project'@'%'.
Or if you want to restrict which hosts can be used to connect to the database, you can use hostname or IP instead of %.

Here's some documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//adding-users.html

If you can log in from command line, run these commands:

```
CREATE USER 'mesh_project'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP ON mesh_database.* TO 'mesh_project'@'%';
```

Change 'password' to something else and add only privileges you want the user to be able to perform. Giving too much power to be accessible from any host increases security risk.

Comment: hey kride, i'm not clear about this.i make my database using phpmyadmin.how i make such user 'mesh_project'@'%'????

Comment: You can create it from phpmyadmin. Click on 'Privileges' tab and 'Add a new user'. Make it similar to existing one but on 'Host' field, put '%' (which is wildcard for any host).

Comment: thanks kride for replay. but in my phpmyadmin there is no option like 'Privileges'...so what should i do??plzzz help

Comment: Probably you logged in as user without privileges to add new users. Can you login as 'root' to phpmyadmin? Or from command line: 'mysql -u root -p mesh_database' (not sure about how it's done in Windows)

Comment: thanks problem solved.hosting provider blocked other ip to access mysql.now they unblock my ip and now its working.thanks for helping..do u expert in php??if u are i want to contact with u.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your host must set to localhost, you can check this in your web panel of your hoster.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your host, in most cases websites and databases are on the same machine try localhost or ask your host provider for the database connection info.